# Laravel 5.2.45 Method store does not exist

Tags: laravel-5

I am trying to copy a file to my server Public Folder.

I am getting the following error :

BadMethodCallException in Macroable.php line 74: Method store does not exist.

This is the html to upload the file :

```
 <form action="/leads/csvFiles" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                            {{csrf_field()}}
                            <input type="file" name="csvfile" />
                            <input type="submit"/>
                        </form>
```

And here is the Route:

```
Route::post('leads/csvFiles', function(){

request()->file('csvfile')->store('Public');
return back();


});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`store()` method has been implemented from Laravel 5.3, you need to use something like:

```
Route::post('leads/csvFiles', function(){
    $request->file('csvfile')->move('Public');
    return back();
});
```

Its advised to check first if file is valid:

```
if ($request->file('csvfile')->isValid()) {
    //next code here
}
```

Then you you can actually save the file with whatever name you want.

```
$request->file('csvfile')->move('Public', 'myfilename.csv');
```

Comment: thanks for the help , i have another issue, the format that uploads is completely wrong and unreadable, any ideas ?

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking, can you open a new thread(new question) giving some more details? and paste link here so that i can answer it. I will be glad to help.

Comment: Thank you , but i have reached my question limit. Basically the uploaded file has no file extension at all. I'll have to wait to post a questions again.

Comment: I have modified my answer which might solve your problem. Have a look.